# I don't understand the meaning of $M_{\alpha\beta}$ in this equation

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry, relative-motion

[image]

I don't understand the meaning of $M_{\alpha\beta}$ here in this equation, is it a matrix, or it is a function of a variable ?

---

Comment: Which book is this? I think $M_{\alpha\beta}$ stands for the metric tensor $g_{\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: (a first course in general relativity ) @SRS

Comment: @SRS This is the derivation of the metric tensor, I'm sure $M_{\alpha\beta} = \eta_{\alpha\beta}$ will follow in the next 2-3 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special significance to the matrix $M$.

Schutz is exploring the transformation between different coordinate systems. Suppose we have some coordinates $t$, $x$, $y$ and $z$. Then we write the proper length $ds$ as:

$$ ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 \tag{1} $$

Now suppose we use some other coordinate system $\bar{t}$, $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$ and $\bar{z}$ then in these coordinates the equation becomes:

$$ d\bar{s}^2 = -d\bar{t}^2 + d\bar{x}^2 + d\bar{y}^2 + d\bar{z}^2 \tag{2} $$

What Schutz is saying is that the two coordinates are related by something like:

$$ d\bar{t} = adt + bdx + cdy + ddz \tag{3} $$

where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are just numbers. So $d\bar{t}$, $d\bar{x}$, etc can be written as linear combinations of $dt$, $dx$, etc. Now you can use equation (3) to substitute for $d\bar{t}$, $d\bar{x}$, etc in equation (2) and you'll get a long and complicated expression like:

$$ d\bar{s}^2 = M_{00}dt dt + M_{01}dt dx + \, ... \, + M_{33}dz dz \tag{4} $$

where the $M_{\alpha\beta}$ are just the numbers that come out after we've added up all the 16 possible combinations of $dt$, $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$. Rather than write out this long and cumbersome equation he is using index notation. If we write $x^0=t$, $x^1=x$, $x^2=y$ and $x^3=z$ then equation (4) becomes:

$$ d\bar{s}^2 = M_{00}dx^0 dx^0 + M_{01}dx^0 dx^1 + \, ... \, + M_{33}dx^3 dx^3 $$

And this can be concisely written as:

$$ d\bar{s}^2 = \sum_{\alpha=0}^{3} \sum_{\beta=0}^{3} M_{\alpha\beta} dx^\alpha dx^\beta $$

The point of all this is that he's going to prove that those numbers $M_{\alpha\beta}$ have to be:

$$\begin{align}
M_{00} &= -1 \\
M_{11} &= 1 \\
M_{22} &= 1 \\
M_{33} &= 1 \\
M_{ij} &= 0 \text{ for all other i and j}
\end{align}$$

In other words he is going to prove that:

$$ d\bar{s}^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 $$

And therefore that:

$$ d\bar{s}^2 = ds^2 $$

So the proper length is an invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a matrix ($M$ is the matrix and $M_{\alpha\beta}$ are its entries) **and** it is a function of $\vec v$. Meaning that the entries $M_{\alpha\beta}$ of the matrix can depend on $\vec v$ (like it says in the book).

Note that
$$ f(\vec a) = \sum_{\alpha\beta} M_{\alpha\beta}\, a^\alpha a^\beta $$
is the most general form of a quadratic function of a vector $\vec a$ (with an arbitrary matrix $M$).

Comment: but what does this matrix equals i mean what its entries and what is  (v) is it a velocity vector i still cant understand it  @Noiralef

Comment: this is the only page which mention it http://imgur.com/a/46RbN @noiralef